# how to compile c++ and not include cstdio and other c standard libraries

Tags: c++, c, header-files, autoconf

I am a C programmer with minimal C++ expertise.  I've been trying to download and install the packages from [here](http://www-sop.inria.fr/galaad/software/synaps/index.html) and [here](https://github.com/proteins/dsr-pdb).  I run `configure` and `make` and for the `dsr-pdb`, I get a slew or errors such as

```
../include/dsrpdb/Point.h:69:14: error: 'assert' was not declared in this scope
assert(i < 3);
```

and for `synaps` I get

```
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../include/synaps   -I/usr/include -I../include -O3 -g -O2 -MT Variables.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/Variables.Tpo" -c -o Variables.o `test -f '../mpol/src/Variables.cpp' || echo './'`../mpol/src/Variables.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/Variables.Tpo" ".deps/Variables.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/Variables.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
../mpol/src/Variables.cpp: In member function ‘std::string SYNAPS::Variables::operator[](int)’:
../mpol/src/Variables.cpp:16:25: error: ‘sprintf’ was not declared in this scope 
sprintf(str,"%d",i);
```

These are errors because they didn't `#include <cassert>` or `#include <cstdio>` in their source files.  I find it strange that two different devs have done this.  It made me wonder if there is a compiler option that automatically uses the the appropriate c-header and library files, or maybe they developed in an IDE that lets them get away with it?  Or perhaps autoconf or make do something upstream of this?

Comment: Those devs' minds are not standard-compliant.

Comment: IIRC the standard allows standard headers to include other standard headers, so different implementations of the standard library may implicitly provide, say, `<cstdio>` if you include `<iostream>`.

Comment: This is not about linking. It fails during compilation and never gets to the linking stage. @melpomene: Yes, and IMHO that's unfortunate. It means that errors like this may not be detected.

Comment: You also have to consider the possibility that this library is simply of low quality.

Comment: I considered that, but I wanted to give them the benefit of the doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc has an `-include` option which lets you force the inclusion of header files from the command line. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_2.html#SEC11